Feature based anomaly detection
I am working on a concept that is new to me in the field of anomaly detection in multivariate time series. A motor is going through different phases (3 phases in total) and in each phase a certain number of runs is done. During each run we do a measurement of 12 features (temperature, angles, etc..). after phase 3 a classification is done delivering: 2 experiments labeled as not operational, 15 as operational, and the rest is not labeled. The problem based on the experts should be happening in phase 2 since phase 3 is simply a back test.
Dataset:
46 experiments on identical motors
4 phases per experiment, each with a variable number of runs
12 features measured over 35 steps in each run (35x12 dataframe per run)
Now here is the idea of the experts. They basically want to answer the question "What features" are causing the motor to be operational or not.
Can you orient me on how to tackle this problem knowing that we do not have enough data as you can see?
